# Struts read value from properties file

Tags: java, struts

I am using Struts 1 (old I know!)

I have a properties file, and I want to ready a value from it as a String where I have the key.

**ApplicationResources.properties**

```
some.key=SomeValue
```

**Java**

```
String someValue = readFromProperty("some.key");
```

**Question**

How do do the `readFromProperty`?

I have tried the following with no success:

```
String someValue = new ActionMessage("some.key").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
String link = getResources(request).getMessage(key);
```